# Replacing digital numbers with graphic numbers on Canvas

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

I've been working on a small game to learn Android further, I've got one question about replacing digital numbers with graphical ones. I'm tired of using Canvas.drawText...

How to create a function that understands which frame to write after which if numbers are printed on a png image?

Ok, let's say I've score 1240, I want to be able to replace those numbers with graphic numbers on Canvas.

I hope I made my question clear, cheers!

Comment: What do you mean "digital numbers" and "graphical ones"?

Comment: Hiya,

score = Integer.toString(scores);
canvas.drawText(score, 10, 10, SPaint);

Drawing graphical score numbers instead of using drawText, text based numbers. 

Example: Let's say numbers from 0-9 is pre-drawn on a graphic format in a png file and need to draw them on Canvas according to the score. When the score is 521, how to pick exact frames to draw them on canvas? never done it before, thought there's a clean way to do it, if you know pls discuss the logic behind it, tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very hard, just place some drawables in correct places. 
But if you want to make a robust widget, you need more consideration and calculation.

```
public class MTextView extends View {
    public MTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initDrawables();
    }

    private Drawable[] mDigitDrawables = new Drawable[10];
    private String mText = "123";

    private void initDrawables() {
        Resources res = getResources();
        mDigitDrawables[0] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_0);
        mDigitDrawables[1] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_1);
        mDigitDrawables[2] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_2);
        mDigitDrawables[3] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_3);
        mDigitDrawables[4] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_4);
        mDigitDrawables[5] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_5);
        mDigitDrawables[6] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_6);
        mDigitDrawables[7] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_7);
        mDigitDrawables[8] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_8);
        mDigitDrawables[9] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.digit_9);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            boundToLeftTop(mDigitDrawables[i]);
        }
    }

    private void boundToLeftTop(Drawable d) {
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int dw = mDigitDrawables[0].getIntrinsicWidth();
        int dh = mDigitDrawables[0].getIntrinsicHeight();
        int width = dw * mText.length() + getPaddingLeft()
                + getPaddingRight();
        int height = dh + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(width, widthMeasureSpec),
                resolveSize(height, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());
        for (int i = 0; i < mText.length(); i++) {
            int number = Integer.valueOf(mText.charAt(i) - '0');
            Drawable d = mDigitDrawables[number];
            d.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(d.getBounds().width(), 0);
        }
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi faylon, I've tried to replace YOUR_DIGIT_IMAGE with R.drawable.gui_numbers, code produces following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Drawable. I've also tried following code but didn't work; gui_numbers = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gui_numbers);

Comment: Thanks for the reply faylon, couldn't get it working, getting error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Perfect, that works! sorry for the trouble, thanks a lot faylon!

Comment: Hi faylon, one more question: how to re-position all the drawn numbers with custom float x,y? It works when I try to display left top corner (x=0,y=0), but it doesn't work when positioned in the custom location with following code: canvas.translate(scoreX, scoreY); //where scoreX & scoreY are floats to display in center of the screen. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!